# Select count of holidays between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the number of holidays between two dates.
I have tried using the query below but I'm getting the following error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

```
SELECT STEP_ONE, STEP_TWO,
COUNT(*) FROM HOLIDAY_TB AS h WHERE h.HOLIDAY_DATE BETWEEN STEP_ONE AND             
STEP_TWO FROM datesTest
```

Here is the Holidays Table. DOW is the Day of the Week.

> HOLIDAY_TB

[image]

Here is the dates table with steps.

> datesTest

[image]

Comment: Please show us the tables you are working with and what is the result you trying to get.. Here you have selected data from a table HOLIDAY_TB and then again you have "from datesTest". It is not clear from this code what is the part of what table and the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT STEP_ONE, STEP_TWO,
COUNT(*) FROM HOLIDAY_TB AS h inner join datesTest
on h.HOLIDAY_DATE>=STEP_ONE AND h.HOLIDAY_DATE<=STEP_TWO 
group by STEP_ONE, STEP_TWO
```

Comment: How do I bind STEP_ONE and STEP_TWO columns to their table datesTest?

Comment: @ChristopherKinyua, could u please provide your table structure

Comment: @ChristopherKinyua, my answer should work in your case

Comment: Yes, that is the correct solution for your question. You can mark it as correct answer. Here is the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16c739d373e2d35715a8db80228f7d96